# html().split() not working in Chrome/IE but working perfectly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a line in my jsp that is not working in Chrome and IE but works in Firefox:

```
var readInnerHtml = $(rowElement).html().split('<input class="')[1];
```

Its becomes undefined when my application runs in Chrome or IE. Can anyone help in this?

My actual function is:

```
function rowAdded(rowElement) {
   $(rowElement).find("input").not('input[type=hidden]').not('input[type=checkbox]').val('');
   $(rowElement).find('input[type=hidden]').val(0);
   var ele = $(rowElement).find('input[type=checkbox]');
   var indexString = $(rowElement).html().split(']')[0];
   var readInnerHtml = $(rowElement).html().split('<input class="')[1];
   var checkForOutputDef = readInnerHtml.split('"')[0];
   ............
}
```

here i observed one thing that `split('....')` working in both browsers but `split('....').[1]` working in only firefox but not  in chrome can any one describe me what i must do now??

Comment: Do not try to parse HTML. Look in the console for what Chrome actually uses - for example the quotes may be single instead of double or the tag uppercase. Use `className = ele.attr('class');` or `.prop("class")`

Comment: i am sorry i dint get you,i am not much familiar with this java script,could you please elaborate a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting my comment for formatting

Do not try to parse HTML. Look in the console for what Chrome actually uses - for example the quotes may be single instead of double or the tag uppercase. Use `className = ele.attr('class');` or `.prop("class")`

```
function rowAdded(rowElement) {
   $(rowElement).find("input").not('input[type=hidden], input[type=checkbox]').val('');
   $(rowElement).find('input[type=hidden]').val(0);
   var checkForOutputDef = $(rowElement).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr("class");
 }
```